# How to use custom path for form_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have these methods:

```
update_holidays  GET    /update_holidays(.:format)                     groups#update_holidays
                 POST   /update_holidays(.:format)                     groups#update_holidays
update_timespans GET    /update_timespans(.:format)                    subgroups#update_timespans
                 POST   /update_timespans(.:format)                    subgroups#update_timespans
```

and want to send data to them using a `form_tag`.
How can I do this?

---

EDIT:
My try on it was:

```
<%= form_tag({url: ##########, method: 'post'},{name: "exchange", id: "exchange"}) do %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple

```
form_tag(update_holidays_path, id: 'exchange', name: 'exchange')
```

and

```
form_tag(update_timespans_path, id: 'exchange', name: 'exchange')
```

Comment: And how do I use custom HTML-parrameters?
I need it to have name: "exchange" and id: "exchange"

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I think my comment was not very clear. I will put an EDIT to my question, to clarify it.

Comment: I will try in a few seconds. Just had a problem with my DB and need to reseed it